# How to connect android app with data store on app-engine

Tags: java, android, database, google-app-engine

I am working with some friends on an android application and we want to use data store on google app engine.
Can anyone help me find a tutorial on how to create a connection between the android app and the data store, I couldn't find a good one myself.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at a few, quite recent Google services:

- Endpoints will help you create an interface between your server code and your client, including generating a client library and doing OATH2 authentication.
- Volley is an Android library that makes it easy to perform the requests to the server.  (There are a number of 3rd party alternatives to Volley that are also good.)
- Mobile Starter Kit is a simple way to get started, doing everything from the client initially, but with the ability to customize the server later.

Take a look at this Google blog post from a few days ago:
http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ca/2013/11/connecting-mobile-developers-to-the-cloud-with-google-cloud-endpoints.html

Those are good starting points, but don't assume you should use the recommended Google services.  Endpoints for example, will lock you into GAE and it doesn't sound like you need the multi-platform support it offers.  You could just create a REST/JSON servlet using one of many libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I reccomand DropBox API.
It is not what you asked, but I guess you didnt start using the Google API because you are looking for a tutorial..

DropBox API has a lot of info and tutorials and it's kinda easy to handle..

Comment: Actually the product we're working on is more complicated than just and android app so we have started using the app-engine